# How to fix 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode charactersin position' in requests.get

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I was writing the spider and when trying to use request the problem occurred.

UnicodeEncodeError: ‘latin-1’ codec can’t encode characters in position

How to solve the problem?
I have tried to change 'latin-1' into 'utf-8' in client.py but it did't work

This is windows10, python 3.7

```
def get_page(slef):
    ##
    slef.url = 'https://www.ele.me/restapi/shopping/restaurants?extras%5B%5D=activities&geohash={geohash}&latitude={latitude}&limit=24&longitude={longitude}&offset={offset}&terminal=web'.format(
         geohash=slef.g, latitude=slef.latitude, offset=slef.limit_num, longitude=slef.longitude)
    #
    # slef.url = 'https://www.ele.me/restapi/shopping/restaurants?extras%5B%5D=activities&geohash={geohash}&latitude={latitude}&limit=24&longitude={longitude}&offset={offset}&terminal=web'.format(
    #     geohash=slef.g, latitude=slef.latitude, offset=slef.limit_num, longitude=slef.longitude)

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36",

        "Cookie": "******* 可用开发者工具捕捉也可用 Fiddler获取  ********",
    }

    t1 = requests.get(slef.url, headers=headers).text
```

and in client.py

```
  for i, one_value in enumerate(values):
        if hasattr(one_value, 'encode'):
            values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')

        elif isinstance(one_value, int):
            values[i] = str(one_value).encode('ascii')

        if _is_illegal_header_value(values[i]):
            raise ValueError('Invalid header value %r' % (values[i],))
```

Comment: please include full error traceback

Comment: I have similar issue when set unicode in referer, I simply `.encode('utf-8')` within try/catch before pass to `.get()` (because I don't want change default library `python3.6/http/client.py"`) worked for me.